# Beginner: Objective C errors in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

EDIT: Thanks Onik IV and Rob Bajorek!!

I'm learning Obj C through a book called Objective C for Absolute Beginners. I'm supposed to create a code for radio stations and am running into some errors. It's a bit confusing because I'm writing the code identical to the code shown in the book.

Header File: https://github.com/williyam/XCode-Projects/blob/master/radiostations/RadioStations/RadioStations.h

Method File: https://github.com/williyam/XCode-Projects/blob/master/radiostations/RadioStations/RadioStations.m

XCode is throwing these errors in the method file:

- Line 11 Method definition for 'setFrequency', 'name', 'setName', and 'frequency' not found
- Line 33 Invalid argument type 'NSString *' to unary expression

Header

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface RadioStations : NSObject{
    NSString* name;
    double frequency;
    NSUInteger band;
}

+ (double)minAMFrequency;
+ (double)maxAMFrequency;
+ (double)minFMFrequency;
+ (double)maxFMFrequency;

- (id)initWithName: (NSString*)newName atFrequency:(double)newFrequency;
- (NSString*)name;
- (void)setName: (NSString*)newName;
- (double)frequency;
- (void)setFrequency:(double)newFrequency;


@end
```

Method

```
#import "RadioStations.h"

@implementation RadioStations
+ (double)minAMFrequency{
    return 520.0;
}
+ (double)maxAMFrequency{
    return 1610.0;
}
+ (double)minFMFrequency{
    return 88.3;
}
+ (double)maxFMFrequency{
    return 107.9;
}

- (id)initWithName: (NSString*)newName atFrequency:(double)newFrequency {
    self = [super init];
    if(self!=nil){
        name = newName;
        frequency = newFrequency;
    }
    return self;

- (NSString*)newName{
    return name;
}
- (void)setName:(NSString*)newName{
    name = newName;
}
- (double)frequency{
    return frequency;
}
- (void)setFrequency: (double)newFrequency{
    frequency = newFrequency;
}
}

    @end
```

Comment: Instead of posting links to your code, post the relevant code (not all of it) in your question.

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time here and working with code. Here is the header and method. I'll edit it

Comment: The right brace character that's supposed to go after `return self` is at the bottom of the file instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw a couple of errors:

```
  #import "RadioStations.h"

 .....
// Change newName to name. (like in header says)


// Change this  - (NSString*)newName{
- (NSString*)name{

return name;
 }


......

- (void)setFrequency: (double)newFrequency{
frequency = newFrequency;
}
// This must be delete }

@end
```